# How do I represent SAMPA glottal stops in IPA?

Tags: ipa, glottal-stop, sampa

I come from SAMPA world, and I am used to using a glottal stop.

In German language, glottal stops are quite common:

For example:

z i ts ? E k @

The "?" is the glottal stop and intrudes a slight pause between "ts" and "E".

How do I do this in IPA?

I used an [online tool](http://tom.brondsted.dk/text2phoneme/?vieweval&l=German) to transcribe Zimmerecke to IPA, and it produced this:

zɪt͡sɛkə

So it either didn't do it right or... hmmm, I don't know.

Thank you!

Comment: Wiktionary has most German words transcribed in IPA (but not every compound noun): https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zimmerecke

Comment: Zimmerecke or Sitzecke?

Comment: Glottal stops may be common in German speech, but having taken German long ago, I don't recall that the glottal stop is a German phoneme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IPA character for a glottal stop is ʔ, hence the use of ? in X-SAMPA: it looks fairly similar to the IPA letter. (Though historically, the IPA one is derived from a right half-circle, which is derived from an apostrophe.)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if each vocal at a word start gets a glottal stop? In SAMPA, it does: ? E p l=   But I didn't see that in IPA.

Comment: @tmighty That's up to the person using it, and the goals of their transcription.

Comment: right half-circle, right?

Comment: @Tristan Oops, yes.